# Protected error in compile time, when no protected class is used [VB.net]

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim box As MultiTextBox = New MultiTextBox

Dim i As Integer
for i = 1 to 3 Step 1

    lengthWidthHeight = MultiTextBox.GetItemValues()

Next i
```

This excerpt of code is using the NXOpen API. In the NXOpen API, the MultiTextBox class is public. However, when I compile the code I get the message:

> 'NXOpen.UIStyler.MultiTextBox.Protected Sub New(ptr As System.IntPtr)' is not accessible >in this context because it is 'Protected'

My question is, how am I getting an error about protected scope? Could it also be that the API documentation is incorrect?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The error message doesn't match your code, it complains about a constructor with an argument.  Please post the correct code.

Comment: That's the exact code that's giving me the error, specifically the "Dim box As MultiTextBox = New MultiTextBox" line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is that constructor that is protected, not the text box itself.  You must use a different, public constructor or some sort of factory method provided by the class (if available).

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of MultiTextBox is marked as protected, so there is probably another way to get an instance of a MultiTextBox object in the API.